# Markdown is reordering my bibliography

Tags: markdown, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying to move my latex file into Rstudio to ease the editing of figures. However, I found that markdown is reordering my bibliography.

My file is of the form:

```
This is a paper\cite{3} about\cite{2} my problems\cite{1}.  

\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
\bibitem{1} \textsc{A. Nonymous}, Title 1, \textit{Journal 1}... 
\bibitem{2} \textsc{A. Nonymous2}, Title 2, \textit{Journal 2}... 
\bibitem{3} \textsc{A. Nonymous3}, Title 3, \textit{Journal 3}... 
\end{thebibliography}
```

When I run it in latex, it keeps the ordering that i chose for the bibitems. Rstudio however changes the bibliography order to 3, 2, 1, that is, the order in which the citations appear in the text. How do I stop this?

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with Markdown. Aren't you just running LaTeX inside RStudio?

Comment: FYI, you might get more attention posting this on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).